# How to save webpage with all styles and images similar to evernote?

Tags: php, javascript, save, html, evernote

If you look at [evernote](http://evernote.com/) or use their [web clipper browser addon](http://evernote.com/webclipper/), it can save a webpage completely with all styles and images of page clipped. So for example if I save this very page with it, it will be saved as is.

Does any one have an idea of how evernote does it? I want to do it with either PHP or JavaScript but am not sure how to save a webpage with all styles and images. I know about Internet Explorer's **mht** format but that's not what evernote does.

So basically it would be great if one can save a webpage with **all styles and images (excluding dynamic content such as JS) in single file and be able to open it in any major browser** ? Any pointer to such script would also be helpful.

I have also noticed similar thing in **Gmail**, when you copy any part of page and paste that in Gmail Compose, it renders it as it was or same happens in **MS Word** too.

Thanks for your help and hints :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace linked stylesheets with style blocks containing the CSS copied from the linked stylesheets. Replace image sources with data URLs.

Comment: Yeah that's what I am thinking but writing algo for that is real challenge here :(

Answer (score 1):

Or just shell out a call to `wget -mk` and [mirror the site](http://lifehacker.com/382509/create-a-local-website-mirror-with-wget):

```
<?php
system('wget -mk http://foo.com/bar');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do file_get_contents() and then go and recursively download whatever scripts/images you need.

Comment: I know that but main point here is about algorithim or guideline of how to save all of those things in single saved page